# Watch Service java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, exception, illegalstateexception

I have created a watch service to monitor a folder.  I amgetting an error once i create or update file from that folder. I have shared my code and error log below. Please let me know how to handle this issue.

//Code.

```
@Override
public void runTask() {

    log.info("Task Running in Lithium **********************************************************");
    log.info("Path *** "+path);    
        try {
           WatchService watchService = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
           path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
           while (true) {
               final WatchKey wk = watchService.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
                    final Path changed = (Path) event.context();
                    log.info("before File changed");
                    log.info("Path Changed "+path);

                    if (changed.endsWith("LithiumRole.xlsx") || changed.endsWith("LithiumRole.xls")) {
                        log.info("Inside File changed");
                        log.info(filePath+fileName);

                        lithiumRoleService.doProcess(ExcelUtil.getWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath+fileName))));
             }
            else
                log.info("changed event path does not ends with LithiumRole.xlsx");

                }
        // reset the key
        boolean valid = wk.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            log.info("watch Key has been unregistered");
          }
     }

  } catch (final ApplicationException applicationEx) {
      log.error("Exception occured!", applicationEx);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    }
```

//Error Log.

> INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
>   already.  Could not load
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser.  The eventual
>   following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging
>   purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused
>   the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:129)
>     at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:82)
>     at
>   org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:228)
>     at
>   org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:191)
>     at org.dom4j.io.SAXHelper.createXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:83)    at
>   org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createXMLReader(SAXReader.java:894)    at
>   org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getXMLReader(SAXReader.java:715)   at
>   org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:435)   at
>   org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:343)   at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.(PackagePart.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.(PackagePart.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.(PackagePart.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.(ZipPackagePart.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:585)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:63)
>     at com.test.am.utils.excel.ExcelUtil.getWorkbook(ExcelUtil.java:311)
>     at
>   com.test.maxup.lithium.task.LithiumRoleTask.runTask(LithiumRoleTask.java:56)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
>     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)    at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)

Answer (score 0):

One of the packages that throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException` is `java.nio.file` which is what you use in your case.

Pay attention to your exception:

> com.test.am.utils.excel.ExcelUtil.getWorkbook(ExcelUtil.java:311) at
>   com.test.maxup.lithium.task.LithiumRoleTask.runTask(LithiumRoleTask.java:56)

I can't tell the line number, but I'm pretty sure it's this spot:

```
lithiumRoleService.doProcess(ExcelUtil.getWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath+fileName))));
```

Make sure to create the file before (untested code below):

```
    Path path = Paths.get(filePath+fileName);
    if (!Files.exists(path)) {
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {
            // log exceptiopn
        } catch (IOException x) {
            // log exception
        }
    }
lithiumRoleService.doProcess(ExcelUtil.getWorkbook(new FileInputStream(path.toString())));
```

---

Also is this `while(true)` a wanted behavior? This loop is never stopping, unless an exception is thrown.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for reply, I tried handling the file path, but still having same issue.

Comment: Can you paste the code sample from your class ExcelUtil.java and line 311 in specific? What are you doing there?

Comment: 'code'
public static Workbook getWorkbook(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        } catch (final InvalidFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return wb;
    }
'code'

Comment: It's always better if you add code snippets in your description. If anything it adds to shed a light to your problem and it's more readable by human eye. Also I can't help to wonder if this while(true) is a mistake.

Comment: Also what version of Apache POI are you using? Can you add that to your description?

Comment: Hi Alex, I found the reason for the error. it is because of watch service, it monitors the folder even after the application gets undeployed from the server(even after server stops). I have to close watch service once i uundeploy the application and stop server.

Comment: @SuchithShivakumar congrats mate. you can answer your own question then ;).